# Automatically accept user input Windows Batch

Tags: batch-file, command-line

I have a batch file that loads on startup that presents the user with a "menu" of applications they can choose to load by typing the corresponding "menu number". **How can we** reduce user input, simplifying their selection, to **automatically pass any key pressed to the command prompt without needing the Enter key** to be pressed after their selection is typed? That is, if a user inputs <kbd>1</kbd>, read that value as if the user had input <kbd>1</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> The constant here is that the menu only spans from `1-9`, so the input from the user will ever only be 1 character long (if that's at all relevant).

In brief how the menu is presented and how user input is handled:

```
:menu
echo [Menu]
echo.
echo [1] - PuTTy
echo [2] - Chrome (Google)
echo.
echo [0] - Exit

SET /P M=(:
IF %M%==1 goto choice1
IF %M%==2 goto choice2
IF %M%==0 goto choice0

:choice1
start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\PuTTy\putty.exe"
goto menu

:choice2
start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" www.google.com
goto menu

:choice0
exit
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Choice](http://ss64.com/nt/choice.html) for this.
So your script will look similar to:

```
:menu
echo [Menu]
echo.
echo [1] - PuTTy
echo [2] - Chrome (Google)
echo.
echo [0] - Exit

choice /c 120 /n /m (:

IF errorlevel 3 goto choice0
IF errorlevel 2 goto choice2
IF errorlevel 1 goto choice1

:choice1
start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\PuTTy\putty.exe"
goto menu

:choice2
start "" "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" www.google.com
goto menu

:choice0
```