# Batch echo variable outside of the For loop then Call typewriter to write all lines in the variable to cmd screen

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I need help on how to solve below problem :

Using a batch file, how do I get several lines of text from inside a text file to be typed inside a summoned `cmd.exe` window, using typewriter.

Let's say I have a text file named `temp.txt` with below sentences:

```
Successful crime is called virtue.
If you are successful, you can expect promotion.
We have made a successful sally.
He was successful in everything he did.
The operation was only partially successful.
I was still striving to be successful.
```

The problem is, only last line would be grabbed, and then written using the typewriter. Not all the texts inside the file.

I've tried to `echo` a variable that has been `set` inside a `for` loop, but that didnt work as it shows `echo is off`.

Below is the batch code:

```bash
@echo off
title %~nx0
color 0a
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set color_white=%ESC%[37m
set color_black=%ESC%[30m

echo pasteclip= CreateObject("htmlfile").ParentWindow.ClipboardData.GetData("text") > temp.vbs
echo WScript.Echo pasteclip >> temp.vbs
cscript //nologo temp.vbs > temp.txt

for /f "Tokens=* Delims=" %%x in (temp.txt) do set SendPaste=%%x

set "text=%SendPaste%"%color_black% 
        
color 09
set Msg="  %text%" 
::Call :menu_[2]
Call :Typewriter %Msg% 

::*********************************************************************
:TypeWriter
Cls
echo(
(
echo strText=wscript.arguments(0^)
echo intTextLen = Len(strText^)
echo intPause = 150
echo For x = 1 to intTextLen
echo     strTempText = Mid(strText,x,1^)
echo     WScript.StdOut.Write strTempText
echo     WScript.Sleep intPause
echo Next
echo Set Voice=CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice"^)
echo voice.speak strText
)>%tmp%\%~n0.vbs
@cScript.EXE /noLogo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" ^" ^
%empty line%
^
%empty line%
     %~1^"
     
exit /b
::********************************************************************* 

pause 

::most helpful references below has been used inside this batch file
::https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369536/batch-file-typewriter-effect
::https://stackoverflow.com/a/36448240/9222942 batch-file-typewriter-effect ANSWER
::https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664957/can-i-mask-an-input-text-in-a-bat-file?lq=1
::https://stackoverflow.com/a/63847096/9222942 mask with black
::https://stackoverflow.com/a/24792070/9222942 mask-an-input-text-in-a-bat-file
::https://stackoverflow.com/a/62121081/9222942 how-can-you-get-the-clipboard-contents-with-a-windows-command
::https://stackoverflow.com/a/21205537/9222942 automatically-accept-user-input-windows-batch
::https://stackoverflow.com/a/16116676/9222942%20how-to-read-file-contents-into-a-variable-in-a-batch-file
::https://stackoverflow.com/a/41926276/9222942 read-a-file-line-by-line-and-save-it-in-variable-batch-file
```

All the text should be displayed on the cmd screen using a guide from [here](https://::https://stackoverflow.com/a/41926276/9222942%20read-a-file-line-by-line-and-save-it-in-variable-batch-file), but when I tried to call the variable to start the typing, it would fail.

Let's say I use the modified below batch:

```bash
@echo off
title %~nx0
color 0a
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set color_white=%ESC%[37m
set color_black=%ESC%[30m

echo pasteclip= CreateObject("htmlfile").ParentWindow.ClipboardData.GetData("text") > temp.vbs
echo WScript.Echo pasteclip >> temp.vbs
cscript //nologo temp.vbs > temp.txt

set "File2Read=temp.txt"
rem This will read a file into an array of variables and populate it 
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "%File2Read%"') do (
    set /a count+=1
    set "Line[!count!]=%%a"
)
rem Display array elements
For /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) do (
    echo !Line[%%i]!
    set "text=!Line[%%i]!"%color_black% 
)
        
color 09
set Msg="  %text%" 
::Call :menu_[2]
Call :Typewriter %Msg% 

::*********************************************************************
:TypeWriter
Cls
echo(
(
echo strText=wscript.arguments(0^)
echo intTextLen = Len(strText^)
echo intPause = 150
echo For x = 1 to intTextLen
echo     strTempText = Mid(strText,x,1^)
echo     WScript.StdOut.Write strTempText
echo     WScript.Sleep intPause
echo Next
echo Set Voice=CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice"^)
echo voice.speak strText
)>%tmp%\%~n0.vbs
@cScript.EXE /noLogo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" ^" ^
%empty line%
^
%empty line%
     %~1^"
     
exit /b
::********************************************************************* 

pause
```

It will only flash the whole text, but then only type the last sentence using the typewriter.

How to get all the texts to be written?

Comment: You must include your `Call :Typewriter !text!` command _inside_ the same `for /L` that "Display array elements"

Comment: i've tried to remove the ```Call :Typewriter %Msg%  ``` that is outside the for /L and added  ```Call :Typewriter !text!``` inside the for /L but it only type the first word of every line and then flashed the remaining words very fast.. anything i missed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call this `Call :Typewriter "!Line[%%i]!"` inside the loop `for /L`

---

```bash
@echo off
title %~nx0
color 0a
echo pasteclip= CreateObject("htmlfile").ParentWindow.ClipboardData.GetData("text") > temp.vbs
echo WScript.Echo pasteclip >> temp.vbs
cscript //nologo temp.vbs > temp.txt

set "File2Read=temp.txt"
rem This will read a file into an array of variables and populate it 
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "%File2Read%"') do (
    set /a count+=1
    set "Line[!count!]=%%a"
)
rem Display array elements
@For /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) do (
    Call :Typewriter "!Line[%%i]!"
)
EndLocal & pause & Exit /B
::*********************************************************************
:TypeWriter
Cls
echo(
(
echo strText=wscript.arguments(0^)
echo intTextLen = Len(strText^)
echo intPause = 150
echo For x = 1 to intTextLen
echo     strTempText = Mid(strText,x,1^)
echo     WScript.StdOut.Write strTempText
echo     WScript.Sleep intPause
echo Next
echo Set Voice=CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice"^)
echo voice.speak strText
)>%tmp%\%~n0.vbs
@cScript.EXE /noLogo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" ^" ^
%empty line%
^
%empty line%
     %~1^"
     
exit /b
::*********************************************************************
```

Comment: sir @Hackoo I couldn't thank you enough for this answer .  but i've another problem which cant be briefed clearly here. so i wrote another question here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73189084/batch-how-to-clear-clipboard-after-get-copy-from-clipboard-using-createobject-h  . hope you could help once again.