# Batch How to clear clipboard after get copy from clipboard using CreateObject( htmlfile ) ClipboardData

Tags: batch-file

This question is based on my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73128218/batch-echo-variable-outside-of-the-for-loop-then-call-typewriter-to-write-all-li) .

Major of these below codes are combination from @Hackoo answer(many thanks to Him) and some other users from SO. And I made a very little effort to combine them with other's codes to arrange a simple tutorial board which can  :

1. paste user input(hidden) using number 1 and automatically entered without pressing enter.
2. typewriting the input with type writer.
3. read and speak the input.

For now, it is working as intended. The full codes is as follow :

```
@echo off
title %~nx0
color 0a
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set color_white=%ESC%[37m
set color_black=%ESC%[30m
:menuLOOP
Color 0A & Mode con cols=78 lines=25
echo(       
echo(       ===============================================================
::set choice=
choice /c 12345 /n /m "   "

IF errorlevel 5 goto choice5
IF errorlevel 4 goto choice4
IF errorlevel 3 goto choice3
IF errorlevel 2 goto choice2
IF errorlevel 1 goto choice1


:choice1 INPUT TYpewriter 
call :menu_[1]
GOTO:menuLOOP
:choice2 PLAY TYpewriter Audio
call :menu_[2]
GOTO:menuLOOP
:choice3 STOP TYpewriter Audio
call :menu_[3]
GOTO:menuLOOP
:choice4 PLAYLoop TYpewriter Audio
call :menu_[4]
GOTO:menuLOOP
:choice5
call :menu_[5]
GOTO:menuLOOP

::********************************************************************************************
:menu_[1] input
cls
echo:
set SendKeys=CScript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"
echo pasteclip= CreateObject("htmlfile").ParentWindow.ClipboardData.GetData("text") > temp.vbs
echo WScript.Echo pasteclip >> temp.vbs
cscript //nologo temp.vbs > temp.txt

set color_white=%ESC%[37m
set color_black=%ESC%[30m

REM for /f "Tokens=* Delims=" %%x in (temp.txt) do set SendPaste=%%x

REM set "text=%SendPaste%"%color_black% 

set "File2Read=temp.txt"
rem This will read a file into an array of variables and populate it 
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "%File2Read%"') do (
    set /a count+=1
    set "Line[!count!]=%%a"
)
rem Display array elements
@For /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) do (
    :: You should call this Call :Typewriter "!Line[%%i]!" inside the loop for /L
    Call :Typewriter "!Line[%%i]!"
    
)

GOTO:menuLOOP

::********************************************************************************************
:menu_[2] Play TYpewriter Audio
cls & color 0A
Call:SkipLine 10
Call:Tab 3
::echo %x% Please Wait for a while .. Launching DJ Buzz Radio ...
Taskkill /IM "wscript.exe" /F >nul 2>&1
Set vbsfile=%temp%\DJBuzzRadio.vbs
Set URL=Typewriter-sound.mp3
Call:Play %URL% %vbsfile%
Start %vbsfile%
TimeOut /T 1 /NoBreak>nul
GOTO:menuLOOP
::********************************************************************************************

:menu_[3] Stop the music
cls & color 0C
Call:SkipLine 10
Call:Tab 3
::echo  %x% Please Wait for a while .. Stopping the music ...
Taskkill /IM "wscript.exe" /F >nul 2>&1
TimeOut /T 1 /NoBreak>nul
GOTO:menuLOOP

::********************************************************************************************
:menu_[4] PlayLoop TYpewriter Audio
cls & color 0A
Call:SkipLine 10
Call:Tab 3
::echo %x% Please Wait for a while .. Launching DJ Buzz Radio ...
Taskkill /IM "wscript.exe" /F >nul 2>&1
Set vbsfile=%temp%\DJBuzzRadio.vbs
Set URL=Typewriter-sound.mp3
Call:PlayLoop %URL% %vbsfile%
Start %vbsfile%
TimeOut /T 1 /NoBreak>nul
GOTO:menuLOOP
::********************************************************************************************
::********************************************************************************************
:Play
(
echo Play "%~1"
echo Sub Play(URL^)
echo    Dim Sound
echo    Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX"^)
echo    Sound.URL = URL
echo    Sound.settings.volume = 100
echo    Sound.Controls.play
echo    do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
echo        wscript.sleep 100
echo    loop
echo    wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration^)+1^)*1000
echo End Sub
)>%~2
::*********************************************************************************************

::********************************************************************************************
:PlayLoop
(
echo Play "%~1"
echo Sub Play(URL^)
echo    Dim Sound
echo    Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX"^)
echo    Sound.URL = URL
echo    Sound.settings.volume = 100
echo    Sound.settings.setMode "loop", True
echo    Sound.Controls.play
echo    While Sound.playState ^<^> 1
echo        WScript.Sleep 100
echo    Wend
echo End Sub
)>%~2
::*********************************************************************************************
::*********************************************************************************************
:Tab
set "x="
For /L %%I In (1,1,%1) Do Set "x=!x!    "
REM                                  ^-- this is a TAB
goto :eof
::*********************************************************************************************
:SkipLine
    For /L %%I In (1,1,%1) Do Echo(
    Goto:Eof
:EOF
EXIT
::********************************************************************************************* 


::*********************************************************************
:TypeWriter
Cls
echo(
(
echo strText=wscript.arguments(0^)
echo intTextLen = Len(strText^)
echo intPause = 150
echo For x = 1 to intTextLen
echo     strTempText = Mid(strText,x,1^)
echo     WScript.StdOut.Write strTempText
echo     WScript.Sleep intPause
echo Next
echo Set Voice=CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice"^)
echo voice.speak strText
)>%tmp%\%~n0.vbs
@cScript.EXE /noLogo "%tmp%\%~n0.vbs" ^" ^
%empty line%
^
%empty line%
     %~1^"
     
exit /b
::********************************************************************* 

:: Most helpful references to arrange this batch:
::https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28369536/batch-file-typewriter-effect
::https://stackoverflow.com/questions/664957/can-i-mask-an-input-text-in-a-bat-file?lq=1
::https://stackoverflow.com/a/63847096/9222942 mask with black
::https://stackoverflow.com/a/24792070/9222942 can-i-mask-an-input-text-in-a-bat-file
::https://stackoverflow.com/a/62121081/9222942 how-can-you-get-the-clipboard-contents-with-a-windows-command
::https://stackoverflow.com/a/31880899/9222942 how-to-play-invisible-music-in-a-batch-file
::https://stackoverflow.com/a/21205537/9222942 automatically-accept-user-input-windows-batch
::https://stackoverflow.com/a/16116676/9222942%20how-to-read-file-contents-into-a-variable-in-a-batch-file
```

But a problem is that, this batch store every clipboard beginning from running the first command 1.

Let say, for the first time i copied *sentence 1* with text "Summarize the problem".
After running the batch, by pressing 1 , the input *sentence 1* should then be typewritten to cmd.

Then when i copied *sentence 2* with text let say "describe what you've tried" , it will repeat the *sentence 1* , and only after finishing the *sentence 1* it will write *sentence 2*.

Even when I do copy for the third time, the forth, it will also repeat from the very first clipboard(i.e sentece 1, sentence 2 and so on)

My question is, how to stop the repeatation of the first clipboard sentence?

I've tried manually delete the temp.txt and the temp.vbs after running the first command but didnt help.

Also i've tried using cmd /c “echo off | clip” which is from [here](https://helpdeskgeek.com/windows-10/how-to-clear-the-clipboard-in-windows-10/) .
I've applied it as follow :

```
@For /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) do (
    :: You should call this Call :Typewriter "!Line[%%i]!" inside the loop for /L
    Call :Typewriter "!Line[%%i]!"
    cmd.exe /c echo.|clip
    
)
```

, but also didnt work.

Could someone please help on how to clear the the repeatation?

Comment: If I understand your problem correctly, you are wanting to empty the clipboard just before you run your command to retrieve the clipbord data. You are retrieving the clipboard data by creating a vbscript named `temp.vbs` then running it to redirect its output to a file named `temp.txt`. Therefore, on that basis alone, somewhere at the start of the `:menu_[1]` labelled section, insert the line ```echo off | clip```.

Comment: "If I understand your problem correctly, you are wanting to empty the clipboard just before you run your command to retrieve the clipbord data." yes and no, the desired result is to clear the clipboard after first attemp (after clicking number 1 and the Typewriter has finished typing). Then when to  try copy from another text, the earlier clipboard has already cleared

Comment: sorry sir @Compo, i didnt notice your instruction earlier. Ok sir, i've done as your instruction, but still the same repetation occur.. is there any other way to do that?

Comment: You never reset `%count%`, so you are just adding each new line to the array which is growing and growing...

Comment: @Stephan , how to reset the %count% ? sorry i'm really noob so please help me.

Comment: well, just before the `for` loop that counts the lines would be a good place for `set "count=0"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As instructed by Sir Stephan(all credit goes to Him), all i need to do is add set "Count=0" before the 1st for loop that counts the lines :

```
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion
set "Count=0"
for /f "delims=" %%a in ('Type "%File2Read%"') do (
    set /a count+=1
    set "Line[!count!]=%%a"
)
rem Display array elements
@For /L %%i in (1,1,%Count%) do (
    :: You should call this Call :Typewriter "!Line[%%i]!" inside the loop for /L
    Call :Typewriter "!Line[%%i]!"
```